# Set Multiple Arrow Directions on UIPopoverController in Swift

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller

What is the syntax to set multiple arrow directions for a UIPopoverController in Swift?

Something like this:

```
popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .Up | .Down
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]
```