# How to set preference to one arrow direction while using multiple UIPopoverPresentationController permittedArrowDirections?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I'm making a pop over presentation view controller where I need to use multiple arrow directions (`up` and `down`). For having multiple `permittedArrowDirections` I've followed [Set Multiple Arrow Directions on UIPopoverController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052471/set-multiple-arrow-directions-on-uipopovercontroller-in-swift). Also I tweaked the background color of the pop over so that the arrow blends in with the background dimming view.

The problem is, I need to prefer the `UIPopoverArrowDirection.up` for almost all cases but for the cases where there is not enough space in right below the source view only then the `UIPopoverArrowDirection.down` should be used. But I can't find to figure it out. The code snippet is:

```
let presentationController = .....
presentationController.sourceView = sourceView
presentationController.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds

// changing the array order doesn't help
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]

presentationController.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0)
self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

For making it clear I'm attaching the current output:
[image: pop over preferred arrow direction]

The source for the demo that I've tried can be found [here](https://github.com/M-I-N/PopupChoice) if anyone needs to follow along.

Comment: You could determine if there is enough room yourself and set the permitted directions to just one value.

Comment: @rmaddy, well. So I need to do manual calculation, right? But other than the height of the popover which measurements should I pay attention to? Can you please point me to the direction?